# Interpolate year-month-day from year, month, and week data in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I've inherited a dataset with measurements spanning 1970–2019. The head and tail look something like this:

```
year  month  week    X1 
1970      1     1   0.21
1970      1     2   0.22
1970      1     3   0.34
1970      1     4   0.34
1970      2     5   0.35
1970      2     6   0.25
... 
2019     11    47   0.063
2019     12    48   0.062
2019     12    49   0.068
2019     12    50   0.067
2019     12    51   0.074
2019     12    52   0.075
```

Each observation of X1 was recorded on the first day of each week (i.e., Monday). I'd like to create a date column in ISO 8601 format (yyyy-mm-dd). Given year, month, and week, it should be possible to extract which day of the month the Monday of each week is. Note: measurements were taken *every* Monday, regardless of holidays.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but you can also try `seq.Date(as.Date("1970-01-05"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "week")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use base R:

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(1970,1970,1970,1970,1970,1970,2019,2019,2019,2019),
  month = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,11,12,12,12),
  week = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,47,48,49,50)
)

df$date_string <- paste(df$year,df$week,1, sep = "-")
df$date <- as.Date(x = df$date_string,format = "%Y-%U-%u")
```

You can have a look at: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime

'%U' converts the week of the year and the '1' is needed for the first day of the week.

Comment: I´ve changed the answer to just use base R

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a one-liner. You can generate a vector of every Monday since 5th January 1970 using the `lubridate` package like this:

```
as.POSIXct("1970-01-05") + lubridate::days(0:2616 * 7)
```

That takes you up to today.

Here's a reprex showing the first 100 Mondays since the start of 1970:

```r
head(as.POSIXct("1970-01-05") + lubridate::days(0:2616 * 7), 100)
#>   [1] "1970-01-05 BST" "1970-01-12 BST" "1970-01-19 BST" "1970-01-26 BST"
#>   [5] "1970-02-02 BST" "1970-02-09 BST" "1970-02-16 BST" "1970-02-23 BST"
#>   [9] "1970-03-02 BST" "1970-03-09 BST" "1970-03-16 BST" "1970-03-23 BST"
#>  [13] "1970-03-30 BST" "1970-04-06 BST" "1970-04-13 BST" "1970-04-20 BST"
#>  [17] "1970-04-27 BST" "1970-05-04 BST" "1970-05-11 BST" "1970-05-18 BST"
#>  [21] "1970-05-25 BST" "1970-06-01 BST" "1970-06-08 BST" "1970-06-15 BST"
#>  [25] "1970-06-22 BST" "1970-06-29 BST" "1970-07-06 BST" "1970-07-13 BST"
#>  [29] "1970-07-20 BST" "1970-07-27 BST" "1970-08-03 BST" "1970-08-10 BST"
#>  [33] "1970-08-17 BST" "1970-08-24 BST" "1970-08-31 BST" "1970-09-07 BST"
#>  [37] "1970-09-14 BST" "1970-09-21 BST" "1970-09-28 BST" "1970-10-05 BST"
#>  [41] "1970-10-12 BST" "1970-10-19 BST" "1970-10-26 BST" "1970-11-02 BST"
#>  [45] "1970-11-09 BST" "1970-11-16 BST" "1970-11-23 BST" "1970-11-30 BST"
#>  [49] "1970-12-07 BST" "1970-12-14 BST" "1970-12-21 BST" "1970-12-28 BST"
#>  [53] "1971-01-04 BST" "1971-01-11 BST" "1971-01-18 BST" "1971-01-25 BST"
#>  [57] "1971-02-01 BST" "1971-02-08 BST" "1971-02-15 BST" "1971-02-22 BST"
#>  [61] "1971-03-01 BST" "1971-03-08 BST" "1971-03-15 BST" "1971-03-22 BST"
#>  [65] "1971-03-29 BST" "1971-04-05 BST" "1971-04-12 BST" "1971-04-19 BST"
#>  [69] "1971-04-26 BST" "1971-05-03 BST" "1971-05-10 BST" "1971-05-17 BST"
#>  [73] "1971-05-24 BST" "1971-05-31 BST" "1971-06-07 BST" "1971-06-14 BST"
#>  [77] "1971-06-21 BST" "1971-06-28 BST" "1971-07-05 BST" "1971-07-12 BST"
#>  [81] "1971-07-19 BST" "1971-07-26 BST" "1971-08-02 BST" "1971-08-09 BST"
#>  [85] "1971-08-16 BST" "1971-08-23 BST" "1971-08-30 BST" "1971-09-06 BST"
#>  [89] "1971-09-13 BST" "1971-09-20 BST" "1971-09-27 BST" "1971-10-04 BST"
#>  [93] "1971-10-11 BST" "1971-10-18 BST" "1971-10-25 BST" "1971-11-01 GMT"
#>  [97] "1971-11-08 GMT" "1971-11-15 GMT" "1971-11-22 GMT" "1971-11-29 GMT"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

using `lubridate` package, you can calculate as following:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(1970,1970,1970,1970,1970,1970,2019,2019,2019,2019),
  month = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,11,12,12,12),
  week = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,47,48,49,50)
)

df$year_first_day <- lubridate::ymd(paste(df$year, '0101', sep = ''))
df$year_first_monday <- lubridate::ceiling_date(df$year_first_day, unit = 'weeks', week_start = 1)
df$date <- lubridate::dweeks(df$week - 1) + df$year_first_monday
df
#    year month week year_first_monday year_first_day       date
# 1  1970     1    1        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-01-05
# 2  1970     1    2        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-01-12
# 3  1970     1    3        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-01-19
# 4  1970     1    4        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-01-26
# 5  1970     2    5        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-02-02
# 6  1970     2    6        1970-01-05     1970-01-01 1970-02-09
# 7  2019    11   47        2019-01-07     2019-01-01 2019-11-25
# 8  2019    12   48        2019-01-07     2019-01-01 2019-12-02
# 9  2019    12   49        2019-01-07     2019-01-01 2019-12-09
# 10 2019    12   50        2019-01-07     2019-01-01 2019-12-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. Notice that I only used the first six rows from your example for this demonstration.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

date_seq <- tibble(
  # Create a data frame with dates from 1970 to 2019
  date = seq.Date(as.Date("1970-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = 1)
) %>%
  # Create weekday
  mutate(weekday = weekdays(date)) %>%
  # Filter for Monday
  filter(weekday %in% "Monday") %>%
  # Create year, month
  mutate(year = year(date), month = month(date)) %>%
  # Create week number
  mutate(week = 1:n()) %>%
  # Join the data
  left_join(dat, by = c("year", "month", "week"))
date_seq
# # A tibble: 2,609 x 6
#    date       weekday  year month  week    X1
#    <date>     <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1 1970-01-05 Monday   1970     1     1  0.21
#  2 1970-01-12 Monday   1970     1     2  0.22
#  3 1970-01-19 Monday   1970     1     3  0.34
#  4 1970-01-26 Monday   1970     1     4  0.34
#  5 1970-02-02 Monday   1970     2     5  0.35
#  6 1970-02-09 Monday   1970     2     6  0.25
#  7 1970-02-16 Monday   1970     2     7 NA   
#  8 1970-02-23 Monday   1970     2     8 NA   
#  9 1970-03-02 Monday   1970     3     9 NA   
# 10 1970-03-09 Monday   1970     3    10 NA   
# # ... with 2,599 more rows
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "year  month  week    X1 
1970      1     1   0.21
1970      1     2   0.22
1970      1     3   0.34
1970      1     4   0.34
1970      2     5   0.35
1970      2     6   0.25",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```